# Is it ideal to call 3 times to the webservice to get data in RESTful model or once and get all it together - IN MOBILE APPLICATION?

Tags: web-services, rest, mobile

We are developing a mobile application(iPhone, Android, WM) which mainly connects with the server using RESTful services. We are in the process of developing the webservices which are RESTful. The question here is .. we have a details window for the customer where he sees his basic info, comments by others, his comments, votes etc. All these are stored in different tables in database.

The Urls are designed like this now..

```
/User/<UserId>/ -- To get basic info
/User/<UserId>/Comments -- To get the comments
/User/<UserId>/Votes -- to get the votes
```

Is it ideal to call 3 times to the server from the mobile app and get info separately or get everything together in one call in proper xml/json format? The concern here is the performance and also we dont want to break the the importance of RESTful webservices?

What do you suggest?

Comment: I've heard that web services should be made "fat" to avoid round trips, but this was a few years before REST was en vogue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RESTful applications depend on caching for performance, you have to strike a balance: larger messages can mean fewer requests due to cache misses, while smaller messages can mean less bandwidth overall. Smaller messages may also be required to maintain proper cache invalidation boundaries. I previously gave a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409877/url-design-for-an-api/4411929#4411929) that might also help.