# Saving a lot of elements RESTfully on a page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, single-page-application

Let's say I'm on a screen editing a post (and its associated meta-data). Now, the post has many categories, tags, and possibly other related items (hasMany).

When saving the entire post, I have to save the post and every single entity associated with it. This is how I do it in AngularJS:

1. All the data is stored in a separate model so that it can be universally accessed. Each related entity has multiple meta-data indicating whether they're new, dirty, or whether they have server-side validation errors.
2. A different controller called "SaveCtrl" manages saving. It goes through all the entities of a post, figures out the ones that have changed, and only sends them along with the post to a single save endpoint.
3. I have a factory that parses the response from the server. An element might not get saved due to a server-side validation error. Regardless, once we get the response, each of those entities have to be updated with the new state and validation errors. This allows the server-side to update entities without any errors, while returning errors for the few that did have validation errors.

Now, here are some problems with this approach:

1. The saving is not entirely RESTful. While retrieving data, I believe I should probably make multiple GET calls for each resource ([URL design for an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409877/url-design-for-an-api/4411929#4411929)). However, I don't know of a similar approach for saving. Should I save a collection, or a single entity at a time?
2. The meta-data for each entity (specifying whether it's new, dirty, saved, or unsaved) has to be put in the model data itself. Since ng-repeat creates a separate scope, I'd ideally like to save such state information in these separate scopes, with the ng-repeat elements wrapped in a controller that'd handle this.

#### My question

Which strategy should I use to save an entire post with all its related entities? Or is my present strategy good enough? Let me know if there are some additional details required.